# error C2244 unable to match function definition to an existing declaration in cpp /// operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to overload =+ operator. there are two of it. One for the linkedlist+=linkedlist, other for the linkedlist+=templated type. But vs gives me an error.

```
template <class T>
const DList<T>& DList<T>::operator += (const DList & rhs)
{
    Node<T> temp=head;
while(temp->next!=NULL)
{
    temp=temp->next;
}

rhs.head->prev=temp;
temp->next=rhs.head;

return *this;
}

template <class T>
 DList<T>& DList<T>::operator += (T n)
 {

    Node<T> * temp= new Node<T>(n, NULL, head);

    head=temp;

return *this;
 }
```

Here the entire header:

```
#ifndef _DList_H
#define _DList_H


template <class T>

struct Node
{
T val;
Node<T>* next;
Node<T>* prev;
Node(T el, Node<T>* p=NULL, Node<T>* n=NULL ): val(el), prev(p), next(n) 
{};
};
template <class T>

 class DList
 {
 private:

 Node<T>* head;
 int size;


 public:
const DList & DList::operator += (const DList & rhs);


DList();
DList(const DList&);
~DList();
bool isEmpty();
void printList() const;
void addToBeginning(T n);
void deleteList ();

const DList<T> & DList::operator = (const DList & rhs);

const DList<T> & DList::operator += (T);
const DList<T> & DList::operator -= (T);
bool  DList<T>::operator < (const DList & rhs);
bool  DList<T>::operator > (const DList & rhs);
bool  DList<T>::operator == (const DList & rhs);
Node<T> * createClone () const;
};
#include "DList.cpp"  
#endif
```

Btw, it's my first question. I hope that asked it clearly and used the format correctly.

The full error message:
Error   1   error C2244: 'DList::+=' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

+= operator used like this:

list4 += list1 += list2;

```
list1 -= 5;



 list1 -= 6;
```

Comment: Where is `DList<T>::operator+=(const DList&)` declared? Are you declaring all of those member functions outside of the class definition?

Comment: before  const DList & DList::operator += (const DList & rhs); line. I declared it as: const DList & DList::operator += (const DList & rhs);

Comment: Why did you not put that in the code you posted? You should edit your question.

Comment: lack of attention

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. What you have right now are bits of code that don't really mean much without context. Where is the definition of `DList`?

Comment: Visual studio still gives error with <T> or without <T>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using templates, you cannot separate function defintion from declaration.

The DList:: prefix may not be in the function declaration within the class body.

You should not inculde cpp files. These files should include header files to make declarations available for the compiler.

Comment: even if they are in the same file, the same error occurs.

Comment: The defintion of template functions must be at the same places where the declaration is. The definition of the first function have to be are within the class body where it is now just declared.